# ASP.NET 1.1 Performance Issue

Tags: asp.net, performance, debugging, profiling

I'm doing some profiling on a 1.1 app and have identified a problem. It seems that this function is taking forever to load on a certain page:

ParserCacheItem System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser.CompileAndGetParserCacheItem(String, String, HttpContext)

I've searched around with no luck about what this does. Does anyone know what this function is doing? If I knew then maybe it would shed some light on the situation.

Thanks!?

Comment: Can you debug in your code and see where the exception is generated. Is it generated when you are putting an item in the cache or getting an item from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Its really a process of elimination.

I've had similar problems where it seemed where I was the only one that had encounted a particular issue.

By breaking my page down I found the control that was causing the timeout/error and did some more specific searches around it.

I then found that the error actually had nothing to do with the symptoms I was experiencing, it was being masked by other issues.

It is an investment in time but you might find that there's some control or part of your page thats timing out for some completely unobvious reason and isn't being reported in anyway. You did hint that page was complex.

Answer (score 0):

What does the page consist of?

Have you tried:

- removing all elements from the page and running the profiler again and seeing if the same error occurs, if it doesn't add each element back to narrow down what was causing it
- are all the namespace references correct for the .aspx?
- have you tried running the app on another box thats running IIS to see if configuration might be the issue?